# R - How pass the environment of a data.table to a function?

Tags: r, function, data.table

I'd like to do this:

for example, i have one data.table as:

```
dt <- data.table(a=1:3, b=5:7, c=10:8)
#   a b  c
#1: 1 5 10
#2: 2 6  9
#3: 3 7  8
```

and i want to pass the environment of one row per time to a function, for example:

```
f <- function(a,b,c){
    x <- a*b
    y <- a*c
    z <- a/b

    return( x + y + z)
}
```

I know i could use in this case `mapply` to solve this multivariate function, but in my real need i have a function that manipulate almost **150 variables** of a data.table, and i don't want to assign the variable's names one by one. I also tried some `.SD` manipulatations, but it didn't work either.

I would like something that i pass the number of data.table row, and inside the function they get the objects **a**, **b** and **c** in the data.table environment.

Something similar to this:

```
f <- function(row_id){
    # set function parent env as data.table[row_id]
    # and *a = data.table[row_id, a]* and successively to b and c...

    x <- a*b
    y <- a*c
    z <- a/b

    return( x + y + z)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to adapt the function to take in a given `data.table` and a row and output your `x + y + z`:

```
f <- function(dataTable,row_id){
    a <- dataTable[row_id,a]
    b <- dataTable[row_id,b]
    c <- dataTable[row_id,c]

    x <- a*b
    y <- a*c
    z <- a/b

    return( x + y + z)
}
```

If you input `f(dt)` it'll give youall of the `x+y+z` values, or if you give it `f(dt,1)`, it'll return values for the first row only.

**EDIT:**
Assuming that you're column names are the variable names you want to assign, you could try this:

```
f <- function(dataTable,row_id){

    for(i in colnames(dataTable)){
        assign(paste(i,"",sep=""), dataTable[row_id,..i])
    }

    x <- a*b
    y <- a*c
    z <- a/b

    return( x + y + z)
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that i'd assign 150 variables manually, and i want to do something simpler, like when the program look for the `a` value it gets directly from the `dt[row_id]` environment.

Comment: @RafaelToledo, see if the edit above will accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: It accomplishes the task, but it's still not what i'm looking. I realize one solution more similar to what i want using  `attach(dt[row_id])` at the beginning of the function and `detach(dt[row_id])` at the end. This helped me but i think this could be done more properly.